# How to get Dart generator functions to act like Python?

Tags: python, dart, generator

I come from a Python, and Irecall that Python generators returns values through the keyword `yield`:

```py
def generate_num() {
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield n
print(generate_num()) # Outputs 0
print(generate_num()) # Outputs 1
print(generate_num()) # Outputs 2
...
```

While learning Dart, I came across that Dart does it a little bit differently. So in the following code:

```dart
void main() {
    generate_num().takeWhile((val) {
        if (val == 2) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).forEach(print);
}

Iterable<int> generate_num() sync* {
    int n = 0;
    while(true) {
        yield n;
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it gets stuck on the while loop! A call to the function yields all possible values, but it's unable to because the while loop is set to `true`. This seems very different in Python where a single call would yield a single value, not all values. Is there way in Dart create generators that behave like Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this is happening here is that [`forEach`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) is going through **every** element of your `Iterable`, and well, that would be an infinite amount in your case.
The Dart version of your Python example would probably look something like this (moving the iterator one element at a time).

```dart
void main() {
  final iterator = generateNum().iterator;

  print((iterator..moveNext()).current);
  print((iterator..moveNext()).current);
  print((iterator..moveNext()).current);
}

Iterable<int> generateNum() sync* {
  int n = 0;
  while(true) {
    yield n++;
  }
}
```

Note that `takeWhile` evaluates lazily, so the following will succeed **and** you can just apply it to your `Iterable` and use the iterator (`final iterator = generateNum().takeWhile(...).iterator`):

```dart
void main() {
  print(generateNum().takeWhile((val) {
    if (val == 2) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }).first);
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I was curious about this for a long time, and given Dart is relatively new, there are not much tutorials online... Glad you helped me out! :)